# Routing process in mongodb which doesn't lets client to know they are interacting with server

Tags: mongodb, routes

I got a mongodb question in my test which is as below:

```
Which Routing process in mongodb which doesn't lets client to know they are interacting with server:
A. mongo.mongo
B. mongoDB.mongoDB
C. mongos.mongos
D. mongos
```

I couldn't find the answer anywhere. Which of the above option is correct?

Comment: That's a weirdly phrased question. The only *binary* in the answers is mongos. "routing process" is not a term I've seen used, usually people would say "routing daemon". Interacting with a server? Of course clients know they are interacting with *a* server, what else would they be interacting with.

Comment: I have used the exact same words I encountered in test( company was barclays) so as to prevent any possible loss of meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mongos.

> The mongos tracks what data is on which shard by caching the metadata from the config servers. The mongos uses the metadata to route operations from applications and clients to the mongod instances

So user doesn't need to know which server they are getting the data from. They just know that they received the data from mongo.